# ¿Por qué la palabra "estrella" lleva una "r" si viene del latin "stella"?

Tags: etimología

Según el diccionario de la RAE, **estrella** procede del latin ***stella***, sin **r**. ¿Cómo adquirió esa **r**? No parece que sea por dificultades en la pronunciación sin la **r**, ya que existen las palabras **estela** o **estelar** [aunque tienen etimologías diferentes].

Answer (score 11):

Según Paul M. Lloyd (*Del latín al español, I. Fonología y morfología históricas de la lengua española*), esa /r/ es una consonante "parásita" [epentética](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ep%C3%A9ntesis). En sí esto no explica nada, sino que sólo lo nombra; la /r/ apareció allí por alguna razón y los hablantes la adoptaron. Lloyd menciona varios ejemplos donde una forma latina sin /r/ pasó a una lengua romance con una /r/ intrusiva que apareció luego de una consonante oclusiva (generalmente ocurre luego de una dental):

- Lat. *stēlla* > esp. *estrella*
- Lat. *phaseolu(m)* > esp. *frijol*
- Lat. *fortitia* > francés antiguo *fortrece*
- Lat. *thesauru(m)* > francés *trésor*

También cita el caso de *estropajo*, cuya forma original española era *estopajo*, y para terminar menciona, en la categoría de intrusiones consonánticas espontáneas, la nasal epentética que aparece sin motivo alguno en el español *mancha* (del latín *macula*).

Curiosamente *stēlla* proviene de [una raíz indoeuropea](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/h%E2%82%82st%E1%B8%97r) que tenía una /r/, como puede observarse en su evolución en otras lenguas (es la misma /r/ que se encuentra en la raíz de las palabras *astro* y *asteroide* y en la del inglés *star* o el alemán *Stern*).

La palabra *estela* como sustantivo común tiene dos significados diferentes, ambos sin relación con el latín *stēlla*, pero *estelar* sí proviene de allí (del adjetivo latino *stellāris*).